# AngularFire with AppCheck stopped working with upgrade from 7.0.4 to 7.5.0 and is throwing No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire

#### Version info

**Angular:**
15.1.2

**Firebase:**
9.23.3

**AngularFire:**
7.5.0

**Other (e.g. Ionic/Cordova, Node, browser, operating system):**

- Node: 18.13.0
- Package Manager: yarn 1.22.19
- OS: darwin arm64

#### How to reproduce these conditions

I upgrade from Angular 12 to Angular 15. With that, I upgrade AngularFire from 7.0.4 to 7.5.0. The overall upgrade of Angular seemed alright, but unfortunately my AppCheck stopped working. In the console, I have the AppCheck enabled via Recaptcha. More details of my setup are in the steps to reproduce.

**Steps to set up and reproduce**

In **app.modules.ts**

```
  imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAppCheck(() => {
          const provider = new ReCaptchaV3Provider(environment.recaptcha);
          
          // calling getApps() is returning an empty array

          // the line getApp() is throwing: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created
          
          return initializeAppCheck(getApp(), {
            provider,
            isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true,
          });
        })
  ],
```

As mentioned in the code comments, `getApp()` is throwing the exception: `No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created` and let angular run in a white page. I tried some debugging and `getApps()` is returning an empty array. So it seems, that there is no Firebase app created in the first place.

I tried several different approaches, which you can find in the issues on [github](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues), here on stackoverflow or their documentation like:

Use `provideFirestore`

```
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp({ ... })),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
```

Use `undefined` instead of getApp()

```
const provider = new ReCaptchaV3Provider(environment.recaptcha3SiteKey);
        return initializeAppCheck(undefined, { provider, isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true });
```

Adding this to providers:
`{ provide: FIREBASE_OPTIONS, useValue: environment.firebase },`

I want to point out, that if I comment out the AppCheck section, my app works and I get a permission exception because of the missing app check token as expected. Furthermore, my setup worked in 7.0.4.

#### Debug output

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).`

#### Expected behavior

AppCheck is initialized with a correct FirebaseApp instance

#### Actual behavior

No FirebaseApp instance is available and AppCheck initialization is throwing an exception, as described in above

Comment: Any new on this matter? I'm running with problems with Angularfire 7.5 as well. Can't make it work by any means. I'm thinking about working with the firestore api, but there's a ton of maintenance to do with existing projects.

Comment: Unfortunately not for me, I completely rollback to an older version like 2 weeks ago..